# how to GET a specific cookie value in Angular 14

Tags: angular, typescript, jwt, session-cookies, ngx-cookie-service

"I'm using the ngx-cookie-service library in my Angular application, but I'm getting two different cookies on every login as already the session id has been SET in the backend, to GET the correct cookie value, How can I ensure that my Angular application GET the correct cookie value using the ngx-cookie-service library (Session id and cookie is set in the backend)

I have installed Ngx cookie service and tried to SET and GET the cookie from frontend but i'm getting two different cookies on every login as already the session id has been SET in the backend (So i need help on how to GET session id and cookie to be captured from frontend)

Comment: chances are the session is an httponly cookie which cannot be printed via Javascript/ client side, you can check it manually on dev console

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the **ngx-cookie-service** library in your Angular application and you want to ensure that you're retrieving the correct session ID cookie value that has been set on the backend, you can follow these steps:

1. **Set the Cookie on the Backend**: Ensure that your backend is correctly setting the session ID cookie. Make sure that the cookie name matches the one you're trying to retrieve on the frontend.
2. **Install and Import Ngx Cookie Service**: Make sure you have the ngx-cookie-service library installed in your Angular project. You can install it using the following command:

```
npm install ngx-cookie-service
```

Import the CookieService in the component or service where you want to retrieve the cookie value:

```
import { CookieService } from 'ngx-cookie-service';
```

3. **Retrieve the Cookie Value**: To retrieve the session ID cookie value that was set on the backend, use the get() method provided by the CookieService. Pass the cookie name as an argument to this method:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CookieService } from 'ngx-cookie-service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-component',
  template: '<p>Session ID: {{ sessionId }}</p>',
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
  sessionId: string;

  constructor(private cookieService: CookieService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    // Replace 'session_id' with the actual name of your session ID cookie
    this.sessionId = this.cookieService.get('session_id');
  }
}
```

Make sure to replace 'session_id' with the actual name of your session ID cookie.

By using the ngx-cookie-service library's get() method, you should be able to retrieve the correct session ID cookie value that was set on the backend. Double-check that the cookie name matches exactly between the backend and frontend, as any discrepancies could result in not being able to retrieve the correct value. Also, ensure that your backend is properly setting the cookie's domain and path to make it accessible to your frontend application.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).